# arcsde - index LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I have a problem with import data with fme and arcsde.
I have a loop of import data in the same arcsde table.

I have a problem with index :

> Error while executing stream insert operation for table
>   'VLORA1A.TEST'.:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-51) Underlying DBMS error.
>   SDE_EXT_ERROR(29861) SDE_ERROR_MSG1(ORA-29861: l'index de domaine est
>   à l'état LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE ) SDE_EXT_ERROR_MSG2()

I drop the index and i register the table with sdelayer.

I think FME alter the spatial index.

Have you a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for that error - http://ora-29861.ora-code.com/ states:

- ORA-29861:
  domain index is marked LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE
- **Cause**:    An attempt has been made to access a domain index that is being built or is marked failed by an unsuccessful DDL or is marked unusable by a DDL operation.
- **Action**:   Wait if the specified index is marked LOADING Drop the specified index if it is marked FAILED Drop or rebuild the specified index if it is marked UNUSABLE.

So you have a bad spatial index.

Your question isn't clear, however you can specify whether or not FME alters the spatial index in the Oracle writer properties.
[image]

---

You can use SQL to `REBUILD` the index after the fact using the Advanced Oracle writer parameter *SQL statement to execute after Translation.* (although the index is updated with updates and insertions so this may not be necessary).

You could also `DROP` the index prior to the transaction using the *SQL statement to execute before translation* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think FME alter the spatial index : Right !

So, the solution is : 
Drop index and when i register the layer with sdelayer, i add this option -R (SRID) and the extent of feature.